How to get values from SQL Server database for Jira dropdown field?
I need help with jira dropdown field. I'm new to this field, so do not judge too strictly.
My user needs to be able to choose some options from field when he opens a task; the options are located in a SQL Server database. How can I deal with that?
Jira is standalone with groovy.
Tried to find solutions in docs, but even

You'll probably want this: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1219994/external-data-for-jira-fields?tab=overview&hosting=cloud

That module designed for Cloud, ours is standalone server
